# How can I use Ansible lineinfile to remove all but a few specific lines?

Tags: linux, ansible

I'm attempting to ensure all but a few specific lines are removed from a file. I can get halfway there with the following task.

```
- name: ensure only the correct lines are present
  lineinfile: dest=/path/to/file
    regexp="pattern1|pattern2[0-9]*|pattern3[0-9]*"
    state=present
    backup=yes
```

Ultimately I want to ensure that `pattern1`, `pattern2[0-9]*`, and `pattern3[0-9]*` are the only lines that remain in this file. I've attempted to come up with a regex that negates this one and then specify `state=absent` but I've been unsuccessful so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only specific lines in your file, why don't you just transfer that file with your desired lines to the remote server? You can use [copy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html) module to transfer that file as is or [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html) module to dynamically substitute some variables inside or even [assemble](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/assemble_module.html) module to generate a file from some fragments(such as config).